# Who are Gothic 2 english voice actors?

Tags: gothic-2

I've been looking everywhere but I can't find a list of all the voice actors for the english version of Gothic 2. There is a list of the german cast, but I would like to research the english actors. Does anybody know any names?

Comment: does the game have a "credits" screen or similar?

Comment: I believe most of the English voices are done by the same actors. The full list of all actors (and producers etc) can be found here: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0889069/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast

Comment: @TZHX If these are the true credits of the game, they don't mention voice actors: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vr2krAGpqy4

Comment: @BiscuitBaker They are not complete. After the fade to black it goes through more, where it does mention voice actors. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bR0RHIKE7sk) about six and a half minutes in for example.

Comment: @TZHX You're right - my mistake.

Comment: Those are the german voice actors. And the list at IMDB is incomplete and also has german voice actors. So maybe I'll never know :(

Comment: I only know for sure that Bradley Lavelle was the voice of Nameless One